# How to log application runs with as much detail as possible?

Tags: windows-7, task-manager, autorun, process-explorer

On windows I have Powershell program running every hour ( that is what I have noticed coming up on the Task Bar.

I have tried to use Sysinternals Autostart and Process Explorer to capture what it is being run, had to do a save and dump of Process Explorer at the right time and compare the results with before and after.

Is there a way to log every time any process/application is run? This way I can just look at the log and see what has been going on my machine instead of trying to capture the process in action.

I have look at tasks and services and cant figure out what is running a powershell command on hourly intervals or what the power shell command is doing, I was lucky to notice it did show on task bar, otherwise would have never known about it, so that is why I am trying to find out how to log every application that runs on the Machine.

I can write a program to pool the running processes every n seconds, and log the new process, but that seems just like bad craftsmanship.

I am on Windows 7 Professional

Comment: What happens if you (temporarily) rename the powershell exe file? Do you then get an error message from the program that is trying to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462756/writing-to-a-log-file-using-powershell) should do it for what you want. Very quick and dirty but logs everything to a log from your powershell script.

For anything else you have to enable the respective advanced auditing settings under the local Group Policy (Computer Settings) and the comb through your event log. [This](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775520(v=ws.10).aspx) will get you started - don't mind the Windows 2008 R2 reference.